# jquery show more of unordered list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul that I only want to show 5 of the items initially. When user clicks show more the other items are shown and the link verbaige changes. Then when user clicks again it has the inverse operation.

```
<ul class="section-titles">
    <li>Section 01 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 02 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 03 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 04 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 05 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 06 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 07 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 08 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 09 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
    <li>Section 10 Title <span>0:00</span> </li>
</ul>

<div class="show-more">Show more</div>

$(".show-more").click(function () {

    var n = $(".show-more").html;

    if (n = 'Show less') {
        $('.section-titles li:nth-child(n+6)').css('display', 'hidden');
        $('.show-more').html('Show more')
    } else {
        $('.section-titles li:nth-child(n+6)').css('display', 'block');
        $('.show-more').html('Show less')
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? Maybe provide HTML

Comment: can you give us an example?

Comment: I think it should be `.html()`, not `.html`

Comment: if(n == 'Show more'){}else{} Also use text() instead htlm() to get the string of .show-more element. Maybe you can try other approach using toggle class for both .section-titles and .show-more, like this you don't need to check nothing and controll all with css (just toggle class in your click event)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7h4N2/1/ ....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    var n = $(this).html();

    if (n == 'Show less') { // be sure to use a comparison operator here
        $('.section-titles li:gt(4)').hide(); // no need to fiddle with CSS here
        $('.show-more').html('Show more')
    } else {
        $('.section-titles li').show(); // or here
        $('.show-more').html('Show less')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/EpZ9J/

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of errors. So solve them and give it a try

instead of this

```
var n = $(".show-more").html;
```

use

```
var n = $(".show-more").html();
```

and for if condition use it like this

```
if (n == 'Show less')
```

and this "hidden" is not valid value for "display" property. Use "none".

```
 $('.section-titles li:nth-child(n+6)').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: The OP should also use `var n = $(this).html()` because if `show-more` is a class there can be multiple, so it may cause an unwanted effect

Comment: This almost works but it doesnt hide when the user goes back the second time and says show less

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var maxCollapsed = 5;
var collapsed = false;

$('.collapse').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      toggleLI();
    });
});

function toggleLI() {
    collapsed = !collapsed;
    $('.collapse').each(function(i) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden')
    });
    if(collapsed === true){
        $('li').each(function(i) {
            if(i > maxCollapsed-1){
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }else {
        $('li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        });
    }
}

toggleLI();
```

});

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/EJYK7/

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate the function when the document is ready to hide the rest of the list. Now it is hiding first when it it clicked. (if it would work)
Also. Display:none is correct. Not Display:hidden